# how to abbreviate dimension following the PEP8 rules?

Tags: python, python-3.x, naming-conventions, pep8

I must add a function for creating 3D textures.
I am using snail case in the entire module.

My choices are:

```
def texture_3d(...):
    pass

def texture_3D(...):
    pass

def texture3D(...):
    pass
```

#### What should be the name of the function?

I am **not** interested in opinions: which one looks better. I need a few references to other modules to see the best practice.

Please mention at least 1 module having similar functions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[PEP 8 states](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#function-names) lowercase with underscore separation between *words* for function names. Now, because it seems opinionated if `3d`/`3D` is an actual word, you'll get conflicts between the names `texture_3d` and `texture3d` (with `d` being lowercase).

Looking at a number of numpy functions, for example, [`lagval3d`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.polynomial.laguerre.lagval3d.html), [`laggrid3d`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/reference/generated/numpy.polynomial.laguerre.laggrid3d.html), [`hermegrid3d`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.11.0/reference/generated/numpy.polynomial.hermite_e.hermegrid3d.html) the name `texture3d` looks like a good choice.

Searching for similar names in [the `matplotlib` docs](https://matplotlib.org/search.html?q=3d&check_keywords=yes&area=default) yields a mixed result between `<name>3d` and `<name>_3d`.

In short, both these names seem to be accepted, based on two major packages. Boils down to personal choice between the two.

Comment: both `numpy` and `matplotlib` are great examples. I will call the function `texture3d(...)`

Comment: sounds like numpy and matplotlib are out of compliance with PEP 8. Not the end of the world, but the question did ask about "following PEP 8", not "conforming to numpy standards"

Answer (score 4):

Rather than depending on mere human opinion, perhaps we could ask the horse? (As in 'getting it from the horse's mouth'.) In other words, use `pylint`.

I modified your code so that it would generate fewer messages.

```
''' some information here'''

def texture_3d(parameters):
    ''' a docstring'''
    return parameters

def texture_3D(parameters):
    ''' a docstring'''
    return parameters

def texture3D(parameters):
    ''' a docstring'''
    return parameters
```

The results of pylint were:

```
************* Module temp
C:  7, 0: Invalid function name "texture_3D" (invalid-name)
C: 11, 0: Invalid function name "texture3D" (invalid-name)

------------------------------------------------------------------
Your code has been rated at 6.67/10 (previous run: 5.00/10, +1.67)
```

Which just leaves the option `texture_3d`.

Comment: pylint is great, my module is fully linted so `texture_3D` and `texture3D` are really bad options as you mentioned. I chose `texture3d` as the name similar to functions in numpy and matplotlib. It passes the pylint test as well.

Comment: OK but that wasn't one of your options.

Answer (score 3):

From [PEP-8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/):

> *Method Names and Instance Variables*
>
> Use the function naming rules:
>   lowercase with words separated by underscores as necessary to improve
>   readability.

This suggests to me that your first option is the most compliant of the three.

Answer (score 3):

**Short answer**: **`texture_3d`**.

PEP-8 says [**about function names**](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#function-names):

> Function names should be **lowercase**, with **words separated by
>   underscores** as necessary to improve readability.
>
> mixedCase is allowed only in contexts where that's already the
>   prevailing style (e.g. threading.py), to retain backwards
>   compatibility.

Since "texture" and "3d" are two separate words, it is good practice to put an underscore between them. Furthermore the function name should be lowercase, so `3D` is *not* allowed.